# Using redis' list data structure or a serialized ruby hash for storing data

Tags: ruby, list, redis

Greetings,

I want to store some data in a redis db and don't know which way I should go. The data is equivalent to something like an address with the variables `name`, `street` and `number`. They will be stored under the lower cased `name` as key, there won't be doublets.

Now, should I save it as a list or should I serialize the hash (`{:name => 'foo', :street => 'bar', :number => 'baz'}` for example) with JSON/Marshall and simply store that?

Regards

Tobias

Comment: I learned about redis hashes (>= 1.3.10) and they seem to be perfect!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using an encoded json object is a pretty good idea. You can see some examples in hurl — check out [how the models are saved](https://github.com/defunkt/hurl/blob/aad75ebfc3fd7d30b411f5426f8bcd7200516a2a/models/model.rb).

Redis hashes are nice too, especially if you need atomic operations on hash values.

Comment: Redis hashes were the way to go, just perfect. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Also you can use something like [Nest](http://github.com/soveran/nest) to help you DRY up your keys:

```
addresses = Nest.new("Address", Redis.new)

this_address = addresses[1]
# => "Address:1"

this_address.hset(:name, "foo")
this_address.hset(:street, "bar")

this_address.hgetall
# => {"name" => "foo", "street" => "bar"}
```

If you need something more advanced, there's [Ohm](http://ohm.keyvalue.org), which maps Ruby classes to Redis:

```
class Address < Ohm::Model
  attribute :name
  attribute :street
  attribute :number
end

# Create
Address.create(:name => "foo", :street => "bar")

# Find by ID
Address[1]

# Find all addresses with name "foo"
class Address < Ohm::Model
  attribute :name
  attribute :street
  attribute :number

  index :name
end

Address.find(:name => "foo")
# => Array-like with all the Address objects
```